# Manually create a kafka consumer group without any consumption

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

Due to the flink issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-24697, I'm trying to manually create a consumer group, so flink job can successfully run, however with below code, I'm not able to create one, am I missing something.

```
val properties = new Properties()
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, broker)
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId)
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, resetMode)
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, classOf[StringDeserializer])
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, classOf[StringDeserializer])
val consumer = new KafkaConsumer(properties)
consumer.subscribe(util.Arrays.asList(topic))
consumer.close()
```

Logs:

```
2022-01-19 12:29:55,006 INFO  org.apache.flink.avro.registry.confluent.shaded.org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser [] - Kafka version: 2.4.0
2022-01-19 12:29:55,006 INFO  org.apache.flink.avro.registry.confluent.shaded.org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser [] - Kafka commitId: 77a89fcf8d7fa018
2022-01-19 12:29:55,006 INFO  org.apache.flink.avro.registry.confluent.shaded.org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser [] - Kafka startTimeMs: 1642595395006
2022-01-19 12:29:55,006 INFO  org.apache.flink.avro.registry.confluent.shaded.org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer [] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-testCG-7, groupId=testCG] Subscribed to topic(s): testTopic.
```

Is there any way to manually create a CG without consuming any data

Answer (score 1):

You need to commit offsets for a group to get created

Comment: tried `consumer.commitSync()` before closing, still CG not created

Comment: You'll want to call `poll(Duration.ofMillis(0))` after subscribing and committing so that partitions actually get assigned.